# How to send list of map into streams in java?

Tags: java, java-stream, jdbctemplate

I trying to run a query using foreach in 30+ datasources. I store the output in a List<Map<String,Object>> this process takes huge memory and long time. Following is the screenshot of the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNYxB.png)

This is my Code:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> resultSetList = new ArrayList<>();
multiDataSourceProperties.getDatasources().forEach((k, v) -> {
jdbcTemplate.setDataSource((DataSource) v);
Map<String, Object> rs = new HashMap<>();
rs.put((String) k, namedJdbcTemplate.queryForList(rsConfig.getQuery(), queryParams));
resultSetList.add(rs);
```

Could anyone suggest me solution for this via stream concept?

Comment: Please don't post link, paste the error itself. Not sure what you expect streams to do if you end up collecting a list of items that are too large to put into memory.

Comment: You should explain what you want to achieve. Why do you collect everything in a single list? You could operate on the data in batches - get data from one db, do stuff with it, discard it. If you really need to keep everything in memory, i doubt there is much you can do apart from increasing available memory.

Comment: I have db in different servers. I want to get the result of the query from all the db to send it to frontend . so i thought instead of using list of map , I could use streams 
 @Chaosfire

Comment: Simplest would be to implement pagination-like, 1 page being the result from 1 db, and the frontend gets everything 1 page at a time.

Comment: The response will be seen in csv format by the end user. How is it possible to implement pagination then? @Chaosfire

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message sounds like the logback is not able to process the message that you are trying to log. Reducing logging should provide some relief from current issue. But overall approach of sending bulk of data in online call is not recommended.

If intent is to share huge csv file, you have 2 options, and both the options involve async programming with threads.

Option 1) Break the calls into 2, first to initiate csv creation and generate the unique id that can used for tracking. second call serve the content if the first call is completed.

Option 2) Use the any of java library/framework that allow reactive programming. Have a look at the options outline in the article https://reflectoring.io/getting-started-with-spring-webflux/.